# How to select fields on an include query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Considering this Models

```
User = has_many :grades (table: user_id)
Grade = has_many :subjects (table: grade_id, name)
Subject = has_many :values (table: subject_id,value)
User.find(:first, :include => {:grades =>{:subjects => :value}})
```

I how do I select the all the grades, then subject and get the total of subject values?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to just get subject value (and it's a number)
You could do

```
User.find(:first).grades.map(&:subjects).flatten.reduce(:+)
```

That should select the first user, then give you an array of all their grades, then map the subjects for each of those grades into array, then flatten out the array, and then add all the values together.